# format function, alternative way to write the following code

Tags: python

I would like to ask if there is any other way to write the following code and also if someone could explain what I'm doing wrong.

Suppose that `x,y` are integers.  My goal is to print the following calculations `x/y` and `x%y` with distance 10 between them.  In order to do that I have to take into account the length of each calculation, so I use `len(str())`, but I get `ValueError: Invalid format specifier`

```
z='{:(10+len(str(x/y)))f}{:10d}'.format(x/y,x%y)
print(z)
```

Comment: The problem is you wrapped all the `(10+len(str(x/y)))` in the string, and Python won't perform any calculation since it considers everything to be string characters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not simply put 10 spaces between?

```
x = 5
y = 3
z = '{:f}{:>10}{:10d}'.format(x/y," ",x%y)

print(z)
```

Output:

```
      # 12345678901234567890
1.666667                   2
```

See [format mini language](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language)

I am putting a single space right aligned to 10 places between the outputs. The decimal is also right-aligned by default and uses the specified 10 places.

---

You could also upp the righmost value by 10 and use `{:20d}` ...